# How to remove cookie use js.cookie & jquery in toggles?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="accordion_container">
    <div class="accordion_head" node-tag="#1">First Accordian Head<span class="plusminus">+</span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_body">
        <p>First Accordian Body, it will have description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_head" node-tag="#2">Second Accordian Head<span class="plusminus">+</span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_body">
        <p>Second Accordian Body, it will have description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_head" node-tag="#3">Third Accordian Head<span class="plusminus">+</span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_body">
        <p>Third Accordian Body, it will have description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my js script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //toggle the component with class accordion_body
    $(".accordion_head").click(function () {
        var tag = $(this).attr("node-tag");
        if ($(this).next(".accordion_body").is(':visible')) {
            $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideUp(300);
            $(this).next(".accordion_body").addClass("collapsed");
            Cookies.set('collapsed_Nodes', (Cookies.get('collapsed_Nodes') || '')+tag, { expires: 7, path: '' });
            $(this).children(".plusminus").text('+');
        } else {
            $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideDown(300);
            $(this).next(".accordion_body").addClass("expadned");
            Cookies.remove('collapsed_Nodes', (Cookies.remove('collapsed_Nodes') || '')+tag, { expires: 7, path: '' });
            $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');
        }
    });
});
```

My question is, if I click collapse, it work, but when I click extend, it can't remove the value from cookie, it will just add the value to the cookie...

Can someone help me to find this problem?

Here is the [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/carry0987/xpvt214o/170365/) link

Comment: I don't know much about the use of the `Cookies` object, but I'm slightly confused about why you are trying to give a value to the remove method, when I would think it would just remove the cookie entirely.  Also I'm curious if the same effect could be achieved by setting the cookie again, just with an expires of 0.

Comment: Or actually if what you are wanting to do is take the tag out of the cookie and leave the others, would you not just get the cookie, parse it, remove the tag, and then set the cookie again with the new value not containing the tag?

Comment: @MaxZoom I fix it, you can try it again https://jsfiddle.net/carry0987/xpvt214o/170365/

Comment: Did you just tryed to remove only giving the name? Like this  'Cookies.remove('collapsed_Nodes');'

Comment: @MaxZoom Sorry for my late reply, the Cookies.remove('collapsed_Nodes'); will just remove whole collapsed_Nodes cookie...

Comment: @JPeter it will remove whole collapsed_Nodes, right?

Comment: @Taplar I just want it can do like this : http://www.coolaler.com/forums/     it can save user's collapsed opinion..

Comment: @carry0987 Yes, it will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing the tag, you can simply rebuild it from all the values that should still be there.  That way it follows the same logic each time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $accordionHead = $(".accordion_head");

  //toggle the component with class accordion_body
  $accordionHead.on("click", function() {
    var $head = $(this);

    $head.toggleClass("collapsed");

    if ($head.is(".collapsed")) {
      $head.next(".accordion_body").slideUp(300);
    } else {
      $head.next(".accordion_body").slideDown(300);
    }

    var $collapsedHeads = $accordionHead.filter(".collapsed");
    
    Cookies.set(
      "collapsed_Nodes",
      $collapsedHeads.map(function(){ return this.getAttribute("node-tag"); }).get().join(''),
      {
        expires: 7,
        path: ''
      }
    );
  });
});
```

```css
.accordion_container {
  width: 500px;
}

.accordion_head {
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 0 1px 0;
  padding: 7px 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.accordion_body {
  background: lightgray;
}

.accordion_body p {
  padding: 18px 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.plus,
.minus {
  float: right;
}

.collapsed .minus,
.plus {
  display: none;
}

.collapsed .plus {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.2.0/js.cookie.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion_container">
  <div class="accordion_head" node-tag="#1">First Accordian Head<span class="plus">+</span><span class="minus">-</span>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_body">
    <p>First Accordian Body, it will have description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_head" node-tag="#2">Second Accordian Head<span class="plus">+</span><span class="minus">-</span>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_body">
    <p>Second Accordian Body, it will have description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_head" node-tag="#3">Third Accordian Head<span class="plus">+</span><span class="minus">-</span>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_body">
    <p>Third Accordian Body, it will have description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Uh..it showed Error {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: Stack overflow has security around setting cookies on their site.  You'll have to try it on the fiddle.

Comment: How can I read values of cookie named "collapsed_Nodes" and collapsed the elements if its node-tag is equal to collapsed_Nodes?

Comment: It can save to cooki, but it can't read, if I refresh the page, it will open all elements..

Answer (score 1):

I have create a code example based on the `hide` class for the accordion_body element. 
Instead of reading the cookies and manipulating its value for selected element, it will always write the value based on hidden accordion elements. 
When nothing is hidden, then it will remove the cookies completely.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //toggle the component with class accordion_body
  $(".accordion_head").click(function() {
    var tag = $(this).data("node-tag");
    if ($(this).next(".accordion_body").is(':visible')) {
      $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideUp(300);
      $(this).next(".accordion_body").addClass("hide");
      $(this).children(".plusminus").text('+');
    }
    else {
      $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideDown(300);
      $(this).next(".accordion_body").removeClass("hide");

      $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');
    }
    adjustCookie();
  });

  var adjustCookie = function() {
    var tags = [];
    $('.accordion_container .hide').each(function() {
      var tag = $(this).prev('.accordion_head').data("node-tag");
      tags.push(tag.replace('#', ''));
    });

    if (tags.length) {
      Cookies.set('collapsed_Nodes', tags.join('|'), {
        expires: 7
      });
    } else {
      Cookies.remove('collapsed_Nodes');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.accordion_container {
  width: 500px;
}

.accordion_head {
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 0 1px 0;
  padding: 7px 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.accordion_body {
  background: lightgray;
}

.accordion_body p {
  padding: 18px 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.plusminus {
  float: right;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>


<div class="accordion_container">
  <div class="accordion_head" data-node-tag="#1">First Accordian Head<span class="plusminus">-</span>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_body">
    <p>First Accordian Body, it will have description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_head" data-node-tag="#2">Second Accordian Head<span class="plusminus">-</span>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_body">
    <p>Second Accordian Body, it will have description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_head" data-node-tag="#3">Third Accordian Head<span class="plusminus">-</span>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_body">
    <p>Third Accordian Body, it will have description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, but I can't give two answers...sorry, but your answer can actually work

Comment: Additional note: do not use non-standard attributes like `node-tag` as some browsers may not render them at all. Instead use `data-node-tag` as per official  [specification](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/10/using-data-attributes-in-javascript-and-css/)

Comment: Thanks for your recommend ! I will edit it to data attribute

Comment: May I ask for how to read the array in cookie? Now it can save the value but can't read it,so if I refresh the page,all elements will open..

Comment: You could retrieve it by `var b = Cookies.get('collapsed_Nodes');` If it does not exist open all accordion elements, if it exists, split cookie string with `|` character `var eles = b.split('|');`

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I will try it after few minutes!

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) , in order to remove a coockie you just neeed:

```
Cookies.remove('name');
```

in your case will be :

```
Cookies.remove('collapsed_Nodes');
```

Comment: I think it will just remove whole cookie named "collapsed_Nodes"